# Java - calculating total with cost and unknown number of items

Tags: java

I have a task here: Define a class PayPerView with method moviefee() that calculates the monthly charges for movies rented. The method should take one argument representing number of movies rented and return the fee as a double.

The rental fee fee is $6.99 per movie.  Preferred customers that rent more than 10 per month get a discount of 5%.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class PayPerView {

public static void main(String [] args){


}
public static double moviefee(int n){

    double fee = 6.99;
    double total= n*fee;

    System.out.println("Your balance due this month is" + total);   

    //return 6.99*n * ((n>10) ? 0.95:1);

}}
```

I know it's awful, I'm sorry and you can ignore that last line of code I commented out because I'm going to redo it and turn it into an if statement. I thought maybe I should use an array, but I can't right? Because I don't know how many movies are/will be rented? Should I use an arraylist for the number of movies rented?

Comment: ya that line looks right to me

Comment: No reason to use an array.  You're close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you'd use an `ArrayList` if you don't have any data to put into it.

You'd probably want to try something along these lines:

```
double total = n * fee;
if (n > 10) {
  total *= 0.95;
}
```

I also see that you wanted to use the ternary operator, so you could replace the above code block with

```
double total = n * fee * (n > 10 ? 0.95 : 1.0);
```

Comment: The first code segment needs `total` to be defined outside `if` block for it to be of use - otherwise the variable will go out of scope as soon as the `if` block is completed.

Comment: Thank you - this is actually a bit easier for me to understand. I made the changes and am not getting any errors or warnings, but nothing's happening when I run the program either. Oh and I did initialize total.

Comment: Did you leave in your print statement or did you take it out?

Comment: I left the print statement in

Comment: From your code block above, it looks like your `main` method is empty...are you calling it at all?

Comment: ...hehe...whoops! Thanks- it runs now although it says the balance is 0.0, but I'm guessing that's ok since the instruction didn't say to provide some kind of made up data for a rental or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that line you commented out looks pretty much exactly what you are trying to do anyway. Is there something particularly wrong with it?

If you really need to output the result on the console...

```
final double fee = 6.99;
double total = n * fee * (n > 10 ? .95 : 1.0);

System.out.println("Your balance due this month is" + total);

return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track

```
public static double moviefee(int n){

    double fee = 6.99;
    double total;
    if(n <= 10){
        total= n*fee;
    }
    else{
        total= n*fee - (n*fee*0.05); //5 percent discount
    }

    System.out.println("Your balance due this month is" + total);   

    return total;

}
```

Edit: added `double total;`

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated because you're recalculating `n*fee` two times in the second branch of the conditional.

Comment: I agree your solution is better

Comment: This will not compile - `total` is out of the scope where it was defined when you try to return it.

Comment: My bad, didn't initalise